# error while creating an xml file from jsp

Tags: java, xml, jsp, javabeans

I am trying to create an xml file from jsp.
This is my GenerateXml.java file. It is located in sap_workshop/WEB-INF/src/MyPackage.

```
   package MyPackage;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class GenerateXml implements Serializable{
   private String wDate="a";

   public void setDate(String wDate) {
   this.wDate = wDate;
  }
  public String getDate() {
  return this.wDate;
  }
}
```

I have a workshop_html_snippet.jsp file in sap_workshop folder. 
The file is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <%@ page contentType="text/xml %>
  <jsp:useBean id="xml" scope="page" class="sap_workshop/WEB-INF/src/MyPackage.GenerateXml"/>
 <Workshop>
   <Scheduled>
     <WorkshopDate><% out.print(xml.getDate()); %></WorkshopDate>
   </Scheduled>
 </Workshop>
```

When i compile the java file, it doesnot show any errors but when i execute i get following errors:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GenerateXml (wrong name: MyPackage/GenerateXml)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your bean like so

```
<jsp:useBean id="xml" scope="page" class="MyPackage.GenerateXml"/>
```

and ensure that your class is in your classpath.

The stacktrace is as a result of the malformed bean name. The format is:

```
package.BeanName
```